I have a approval process that needs a checkbox field to be checked as criteria, now I trying to initiate it to use it on a LWC
`public with sharing class ApprovalProcessController {

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static Id getTheCurrentUserContactId() {
      return [SELECT Id,ContactId FROM user WHERE Id = : UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1].ContactId;       
  }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void startApprovalProcess() {
      String contactId = getTheCurrentUserContactId();
      Contact contactRecord = [SELECT Id, Sheet__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId LIMIT 1];
       // Set the Sheet__c checkbox to true
      contactRecord.Sheet__c = true;
       update contactRecord;
    if (contactRecord.Sheet__c  == true) {
      // Start the approval process
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req.setComments('Submitting for approval');
        req.setObjectId(contactRecord.Id);
        req.setSubmitterId(contactId);
        req.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('My_Approval');
        req.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Approval process started successfully.');
        } else {
            System.debug('Error starting approval process: ' + result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
        }
      } else {
        System.debug('Failed to set Sheet__c checkbox to true.');
    }
}`


Hello, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to learn about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. Please be as detailed as you can about any errors you received, etc, by making an [edit] describing any errors or logs that you may have obtained when running this code.
